# NodeJS Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-apps-script-api

I am trying Google Apps Script API. I receive this

> Request is missing required authentication credential" error by trying service.scripts.run({ // params }).

Can somebody help me figure out, how to authenticate credentials?

I am using google.auth.OAuth2() for my authentication.

This is my code:

```
const service = google.script({ version: 'v1', auth });  
await service.scripts.run({ scriptId, requestBody: { function: 'myFunction', devMode: true }});
```

service.scripts is already working fine with these methods:

```
await service.projects.create({ // params })
```

and

```
service.projects.updateContent({ // params })
```

Here are my scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects  
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
```

I am expecting for the my Apps Script to run programmatically.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your auth object?

Comment: @Dejan here `google.auth.OAuth2(myClient_id, myClient_secret, myRedirect_uri);`

Comment: then  I did `auth.setCredentials(token)` . `token` has `access_token`, `scope`, ... `refresh_token`

Comment: According to the [google docs on scripts api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts) - The Apps Script API does not work with [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)(OAuth2). You can try using a different authentication method too see if that solves your problem

Comment: Note that what I mentioned is only if you are using a service account.

Comment: thanks @Dejan for answering! However I am not using service account. But I will try different authentication method